# PowerShell run as administrator from taskbar not launching correctly

Tags: windows-10, powershell, taskbar

In Windows 10 (1909) I'm having some odd results when using the `Run as administrator` task from a PowerShell taskbar shortcut.

[image]

The window launches but does not finish launching and I cannot input any commands in the window.

[image]

If I right click on a different taskbar shortcut (e.g. Microsoft Teams) whilst the window is open it finishes launching and I can now input commands.

[image]

Looking at the shortcut created in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` the target is `%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit`.

[image]

If I right click Run as administrator directly on the shortcut in this folder PowerShell launches correctly.

Does anyone know why I am getting this behaviour and a possible solution so it launches correctly?

Comment: Have you tried unpinning the app from your taskbar, then launch the working shortcut, and pin it again?

Comment: Yes. When I search for powershell.exe via the start menu there is no pin to taskbar option so I have to launch it and then pin.

Comment: Yes, there is, just right-click the lin when it shows up. Even if there was not, you can create your own shortcut on your desktop, change the settings as needed and pin to the taskbar then use the advanced settings to permanently set the checkbox to always run as admin. Your screenshot already shows it is on your taskbar, hence the unpin thing. So, unpin it and repin it.